# jQuery / JS and HTML entity decoding.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-entities, html-encode

I've got this HTML entity I need to use as the title attribute and href attribute on a link (`&#8211;`) how do I escape/decode this for use? I'm using jQuery, do either a vanilla jS or jQuery method would be great!
Part of my code:

```
newListElement.children( "a" ).attr({
   "href" : this.permalink,
   "title" : this.title
}).html( this.title );
```

The html() method works fine, but I don't think I can use that in the object where I'm setting the title..?

I've read some other answers on SO, but I couldn't find anything which explains how to do this when you're setting the values in an object like I am in my script.

Thanks for taking a look, Dan.

Comment: Did you try?  All you say is you "don't think"... nothing compares to giving it a shot and if you then get errors, ask for help. ;)

Comment: @JeremyMiller - yes, I had already, but wasn't sure on the syntax, and don't want to clutter the page with all my failed attempts for what it likely to be a simple issue for someone with more knowledge than me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
function escapeMyHtml(input){
   return input.replace(/-/g, '&#8211;');
}
```

Call it like this:

```
escapeMyHtml('a-b');//a&#8211;b
```

Comment: That's cool, but obviously it's only useful if I'm dealing with that exact character, I was thinking of using something more versatile.

Comment: what all to you want to escape?

Comment: Whatever really, even a fraction: &#188; That's not really the point - I was originally trying to find a method which already does this. If there isn't one, then I'll need something like you've written in your answer.

Comment: There is no method that does it for you. You have to manually do it

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting me know. I wonder if this is anything I can solve by changing the json_encode() in my PHP that creates this issue in the first place..